# Rails callback changed in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here I want to verify that the attribute has changed in my model

model columns

```
Customer
ID
First
Last
curr_gender
```

Model

```
  before_update :gender_changed
    protected
    def gender_changed
      self.curr_gender.changed?
        #do code
    end
```

But i guess the following error

```
NoMethodError in CustomersController#update

undefined method `changed?' for "2":String
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's `curr_gender_changed?`